# What mysql connector do my program need?

Tags: mysql, exe

I have to run a .exe emulator, but it needs the right mysql connector version. How do i check what mysql connector version it needs?

Comment: It depends on you mysql version. If you found the version number you have to read the documentation.

Comment: The latest one that matches your language.